# Suggestions for nonparametric machine learning models

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-science, artificial-intelligence

I am new to machine learning, but I have decent experience in python. I am faced with a problem: I need to find a machine learning model that would work well to predict the speed of a boat given current environmental and physical conditions. I have looked into Scikit-Learn, Pytorch, and Tensorflow, but I am having trouble finding information on what type of model I should use. I am almost certain that linear regression models would be useless for this task. I have been told that non-parametric regression models would be ideal for this, but I am unable to find many in the Scikit Library. Should I be trying to use regression models at all, or should I be looking more into Neural Networks? I'm open to any suggestions, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think multi-linear regression model would work well for your case. I am assuming that the input data is just a bunch of environmental parameters and you have a boat speed corresponding to that. For such problems, regression usually works well. I would not recommend you to use neural networks unless you have a lot of training data and the size of one input data is also quite big.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I have about 200,000 rows of data, and 22 different columns of variables. Would neural networks be useful for a data size this large?

Comment: Yea I guess you could try using simple NN too. But I cannot say at the moment, which type of ML algorithm would be best for your case. Perhaps you can compare the performance of NN and regression if you want. In general, the NNs would be more memory intensive.

Comment: Thank you so much, I appreciate it! I would upvote your comments if my account wasn't so new, sorry about that.